# Is there any way to programmatically delete my own iOS app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there any way within the iOS SDK for an app to delete itself?

I'm seeking the following behavior:

1. If a user fails to enter the correct password to log in (5 times)
2. The app deletes all user data AND deletes itself from the iPhone.

I understand how to delete all user data.  I'm just asking if it's possible to delete the app as well.

Comment: I think you've been watching too much Mission Impossible ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, only the user (or iTunes, or Xcode's Organizer) can remove applications from the device.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. All your app can do is delete its user data and refuse to do anything else. Removing it from the system is entirely up to the user.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. I don't know about jailbroken devices though.