# How do I programmatically remove an application from an iOS device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically delete my own app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811994/programmatically-delete-my-own-app)

Currently I am working on a iphone application and one of the critical requirement of the application is if a user cannot successfully authenticate after 5 attempts, the application is removed from the user’s iPhone.

How can I achieve this goal?

Comment: The USER is in control of their device and what is or isn't installed on it, NOT YOU.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being able to alter things outside of the application's own sandbox is a huge security risk that Apple (understandably) has not allowed.  Therefore you will not be able to do this.  The best you can do is store the result in a persistent value and not allow to app to continue after launching.  For bonus points, you can store this value in the iOS keychain so that it will persist between installs if you like, then the user will be forced to reset their ios device to factory defaults to be able to use it again.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done. The best you can do is to make your app stop functioning after five failed authentication attempts.

Answer (score 1):

you cant. the only one who can have this privilige is the user. You could just make the app to not open anymore, making the user angry and then deleting it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible. You should handle it programmatically like locking the application. Once user is failed for 5 attempts, change your startup viewcontroller and do not allow the user to  navigate any where else. Here you can display some message to delete the app.

Answer (score 0):

An application, installed in a non-jailbroken device, is a sandboxed eco-system. 
If your app is for App Store, this thing cannot be done. If this app is for a JB device (for In-House apps would be possible, but I think you need root permissions to delete apps), try to remove the app file from disk after the app has gone on background (but I'm quite sure files are locked, so you'll not be able to do it). If this approach, as I guess, doesn't work due to locked files, you can try to search for private APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You only solution is lock the app if authentication not success.