# Remove app before simulator or device is lunched from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Is there any scrip or built in feature to remove application from simulator or device before we lunched new one.

So each time I changed data model layer in core data app crashes and also there are other reasons to have simulator or device without previous installation.

So each time I hit Run button on Xcode I want to automatically drop already installed app (for sure with the same bundle id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible as you want and still there is no way to achieve this

Please refer this link:
[How do I programmatically remove an application from an iOS device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906174/how-do-i-programmatically-remove-an-application-from-an-ios-device)

It indirectly guide your question, it also showing no possibility of this feature.

Comment: ok thanks, I guess then it's better to implement some if debug code where I will remove all data. Thought there is still some risk to have uncleared data.