# Can uninstall iOS app or delete configuration profile in app?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to let my iOS App uninstall or Configuration Profile delete when I click confirm button in this app.

Can I do this with Swift code or can't do because Apple Security Mechanism?

Comment: It is not possible. Check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906174/how-do-i-programmatically-remove-an-application-from-an-ios-device

Comment: Configuration Profile can't delete too?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/106799 not possible to use on macOS, and I found only workarounds for jailbreak. I think it isn't possible (maybe you can find some trick) but clear way doesn't exist

Comment: Okay. Thank you!

Comment: no problem! your welcome