# xcode: I want to simulate delete functionality for an app, but don't know how?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

As we can see in this image:
[image]

How do we simulate same functionality programmatically?

Please provide any links of some code to active this.

---

### EDIT:

Sorry: If I wasn't clear, actually I am developing an App that has few Buttons with Back Ground images. There's a functionality to add bookmarks, whenever user clicks to add in bookmark the new button is created on screen. Now I have to delete the bookmarks from screen & to do that I had performed the slide up to delete book mark, but that doesn't animate that button, also the requirement is just to keep pressing the screen without sliding up to delete.

code to swipe up detection is:

```
- (void) handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {
    NSLog(@"swiping up..");
    //some code here.. to display Deletion Icon on the corner of the button
}
```

but I don't know how to Identify the touch press event just like is being done in Iphone to delete Apps.

Thanks
Ashish

Comment: What parts of the functionality do you need to replicate? What part are you stuck on?

Comment: Where you want to implement that ? In your app ?

Comment: I think this question has already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811994/programmatically-delete-my-own-app

Comment: I have updated my question, plz check.

Comment: I have noticed that you have changed the entire structure of your question, this is not a good practice. Be specific when you ask something, you can improve your questions, but donot change the entire question when you feel that the question was of low quality. If you have anew question to ask, ask it as  a **new question**.Please don't add it as a tail to your existing questions which has accepted or scored answers.

Comment: @MicRO Ashish clarified his question. It was a legitimate edit.

Comment: @MICRO : so, well can you tell me how can I simulate the same functionality except deleting an App (I would delete any object or perform any other logic), but the behavior should remain same.

Comment: If your goal is simply to detect a long press, look at `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.  If you want to jiggle the buttons like the home screen does, just animate each button's `transform` property.

Comment: @robmayoff Look at his screenshot and now he is diverting to gesturerecognizer! What sense does this make? I posted my answer when his question was something else, and now it seems outdated or offtopic to someone who visits this questions after a few days!

Comment: thanks a lot for guiding me in right direction.

Comment: To me his original question read like someone who wants to implement a UI similar to springboard's deletion UI, but doesn't speak English well enough to express that very well.  When he saw that he was being misunderstood, he clarified.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: @MICRO: Sorry, If I couldn't clear my question first time. But now I'll take care of that also. plz. don't get bothered.

Comment: Its ok...no worries. Told just to make you aware..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great help by **rob mayoff** to guid me in right direction.

**------------------
Edit:-------------**

**Note:** *This doesn't exaclty displays as in iPhone while deleting any App, but still that can be achieved easily as this animates in different manner.*

**------------------**

The following way I achieved the deletion functionality for my code:

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)swipe
{
   if (swipe.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
   {
    NSLog(@"long pressed up..");
    @try {
        UIButton *btnDelete = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:977];
        [btnDelete removeFromSuperview];

        if(self.btnIDToDelete == swipe.view.tag)
        {
            self.btnIDToDelete = -1;
            UIButton *btnToDelete = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:swipe.view.tag];
            CALayer *layer = btnToDelete.layer;
            [layer removeAnimationForKey:@"DeleteAnimation"];
            return;
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }
    @finally {

    }

    NSInteger tag = swipe.view.tag;
    NSLog(@"id is = %d", tag);
    self.btnIDToDelete = tag;
    UIButton *btnToDelete = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
    UIButton *btnDelete = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(btnToDelete.frame.origin.x - 1, btnToDelete.frame.origin.y + 45, 50, 49)];
    [btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteFavButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnDelete.tag = 977;
    UIImage *imgBack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"crossIpad.png"];
    [btnDelete setBackgroundImage:imgBack forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.view addSubview:btnDelete];
    [btnDelete release];


    CABasicAnimation *pulseAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    pulseAnimation.duration = .5;
    pulseAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.1];
    pulseAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    pulseAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
    pulseAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX;
    //pulseAnimation.repeatCount = 5;
    //pulseAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    //pulseAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    pulseAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
    pulseAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    float xVal = btnToDelete.frame.origin.x;
    float yVal =btnToDelete.frame.origin.y;
    float widthVal = btnToDelete.frame.size.width;
    float heightVal = btnToDelete.frame.size.height;


    NSLog(@"-- xVal=%f -- yVal=%f -- widthVal=%f -- heightVal=%f -- ",xVal, yVal, widthVal, heightVal);

    if(xVal < 48)
        xVal = 48;
    else if (xVal > 250 && xVal < 278)
        xVal = 278;
    else if (xVal > 480 && xVal < 508)
        xVal = 508;

    if(yVal < 95)
        yVal = 95;
    else if(yVal > 250 && yVal < 310)
        yVal = 310;
    else if(yVal > 500 && yVal < 525)
        yVal = 525;


    [btnToDelete setFrame:CGRectMake(xVal, yVal, widthVal, heightVal)];
    CALayer *layer = btnToDelete.layer;
    [layer addAnimation:pulseAnimation forKey:@"DeleteAnimation"];


   }
}
```

You should call this like :

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [btn addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
    [longPress release];
```

Note: Show appropriate message in **"deleteFavButton"** method and handle deletion code there.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to delete your app programatically , let me tell you, **NO You can't**.
Apple provides a default way to do it.So you don't need to add a new method to do it yourself.

There are two methods by which you can do it.

1.*How to Delete Applications Directly from Your iDevice.*

If you want to delete an application off of your iPhone, iPod Touch or iPad, it is a simple process to accomplish this task.

~Locate the application you want to delete

~Double tap the item, but keep your finger held on the screen. You will here a tone and VoiceOver will announce, “moving application name

~Double tap the item again.

**AND**

2.*How to Delete applications for your iDevice in iTunes*

If you don’t want to delete an application directly from your iPhone, iPad or iPod Touch, you can do it in iTunes. Simply do the following;

~Open up iTunes and interact with the source table

~Go to Applications and stop interacting with the table

~Go to the list of actual applications and navigate to the app you want to delete

~Hit the delete key on your keyboard and then theVO keys and spacebar on the, remove, button, when the confirmation dialog box comes up

~Then, decide whether you want the file permanently removed or only removed from your iTunes library

You will then be asked if you are sure if you want to delete the application. Just double tap the “delete” button to confirm your decision or the “cancel” button if you change your mind.

Comment: I have updated my question plz. check