# Programmatically uninstall/remove app on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

I have been struggling on a project for few weeks but yet, still no fruity result.
Having an app that is running on ios ipad, built using Objective-C.

I have a requirement to remove inhouse app if the app was not logged in for x number of days. It is in-house app, not on appstore.
I have tried imkira mobiledevice and libimobiledevice.
But nothing working.

Hoping for guru to give me some advise.
Thanks

Similar to post
[Programmatically delete my own app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811994/programmatically-delete-my-own-app)

[How do I programatically remove an application from an iphone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906174/how-do-i-programatically-remove-an-application-from-an-iphone-device)

Comment: The app to be removed on offline and not via any Mobile Device Management.

Comment: No you can't. You can however check if the App is Expired, Show the notification to user that he has to remove the app and stop all operations.

Comment: If there are previous answers saying the same thing that it's not possible, why post a new question unless iOS releases some mechanism to do that with recent updates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programatically remove an application from an iphone device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906174/how-do-i-programatically-remove-an-application-from-an-iphone-device)

Comment: I have seen other enterprise's application and it can be removed.
However, they are not allowed to disclose the mechanism behind it

Answer (score 1):

You can not remove or uninstall an app *programatically*. The best you can do is quit the app by using `exit(0);` but can get your app rejected if the app just quits without letting the user know.

Comment: Mine is in house app (Enterprise development), not going for AppStore.
Now, trying other method, NSTask but the program doesn't execute...

Comment: NSTask is for macOS afaik and have a chance of deleting your own app there. But no way can you do this for iOS. Apple don't allow you to control anything out of your app. If you say you've seen people accomplish this before, then it is most probably jailbroken. Or they used a configuration profile.